# Oncomplete event of actionFunction is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce

I have created a visualforce page which uses jQuery to call a function and create a pop up. The ActionFunction tag uses an Oncomplete event which calls the jQuery function.

Now I'm trying to make two pop ups, but the Oncomplete event of actionFunction is not working.

```
<apex:page controller="DataCleanUp" showHeader="false" sidebar="false"> 
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.jQueryPlugin}"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap_sf1_beta16, 'bootstrap-sf1-0.1.0-beta.16/dist/css/bootstrap.css')}" />
    <script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.js"/> 

      <script>

        j$=jQuery.noConflict();
        j$(document).ready(function(){
            j$("#popUp").dialog({autoOpen:false,model:true,position:'center',width: 1000});

        });
        function showDialog(depenList){
            j$("#dependentObj").html(depenList);
            j$("#popUp").dialog("open");
            j$("#popUp").dialog("option","title","Number of Records");
            j$("#popUp").dialog('option','position','center');
            return false;
        }

     </script>

     <apex:form >
         <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
         <apex:actionFunction action="{!checkAllStd}" name="checkStd" reRender="standardTable"/>
           <apex:actionFunction action="{!checkAllCustom}" name="checkCus" reRender="customTable"/>  
           <apex:actionFunction action="{!QueryCount}" name="countObj"  oncomplete="return showCount('{!count}');" reRender="example">
                <apex:param name="objCount" value="" id="RecordsCount" assignTo="{!objCount}"/>
           </apex:actionFunction>
           <apex:pageBlock title="Standard Data Clean Up" >
               <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageId" title="Standard Objects" columns="4" collapsible="true">
                   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!standardWrapObjList}" var="wObj"  id="standardTable" align="center" title="Standard Objects" styleClass="table">
                       <apex:column >
                           <apex:facet name="header" ><apex:inputCheckbox onclick="checkStd()" value="{!standardFlag}"/></apex:facet>
                           <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wObj.isSelected}" id="InputId" label="Object Name"/> 
                       </apex:column>
                       <apex:column > 
                           <apex:facet name="header" >Object Name</apex:facet> 
                           {!wObj.objName} 
                       </apex:column>
                       <apex:column > 
                           <apex:facet name="header" >Number of Records</apex:facet> 
                           <apex:outputLink onclick="countObj('{!wObj.objName}');return false; " >
                               See Number of Records
                           </apex:outputLink>
                           </apex:column>
                     </apex:pageBlockTable>
               </apex:pageBlockSection>
               <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete"  action="{!dependentStdtObjList}"    oncomplete="return showDialog('{!depenStdList}');"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancleStandardDelete}" value="Cancle"/>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteStdRecords}" value="confirm" />

               </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         </apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlock title="Custom Data Clean Up" >
             <apex:pageBlockSection id="pageId" title="Custom Objects" columns="4" collapsible="true">
                 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!customWrapObjList}" var="wObj"  id="customTable" align="center" title="Custom Objects" styleClass="table" >
                     <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header" ><apex:inputCheckbox onclick="checkCus()" value="{!customFlag}"/></apex:facet> 
                         <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wObj.isSelected}" id="InputId" label="Object Name"/> 
                     </apex:column>
                     <apex:column > 
                         <apex:facet name="header" >Object Name</apex:facet> 
                           {!wObj.objName} 
                     </apex:column>
                     <apex:column > 
                         <apex:facet name="header" >Number of Records</apex:facet> 
                         <apex:outputLink onclick="countObj('{!wObj.objName}')">
                               See Number of Records
                         </apex:outputLink>
                     </apex:column>
                 </apex:pageBlockTable> 
             </apex:pageBlockSection>
             <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Delete"  action="{!dependentCustObjList}"  reRender="pageId"  oncomplete="return showDialog('{!depenCustomList}')"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancleCustomDelete}" value="Cancle"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!deleteCusRecords}" value="confirm" />
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         </apex:pageBlock>
         <div id ="popUp">
         <div style = "float:left" >This object's records are also getting deleted</div>
         <div id = "dependentObj"></div>
         </div>
         <apex:pageBlock id="example"></apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using action functions correctly, I recommend you read the docs and post this question in Salesforce Stack

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm